# Calculate how much scrolling is needed for a container element to make one of the its children element visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, overflow

There is a div element with specified height and it contains lots of span elements so scrolling is needed to see elements which are initially invisible due to overflow.

I need to calculate how much scrolling is needed in order to make them visible ?

Thank you.

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow-y:scroll;">
    <div>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child123</span>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child35</span>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child34343</span>
        <span>child</span>
        <span>child</span>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to know the max possible amout of scroll? Or the amout of scroll needed to get to a particular element?

Comment: @galambalazs amout of scroll needed to get to a particular element

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can iterate through these child elements and ask them for their position in relation to wrapping div. After that if y-position is more than height of div you can just subtract div's height from y-position and you will get desired number.

If you provide snippet of your code or link to real page I could show you appropriate js code.

Comment: What is the js function to find the position of a child in relation to wrapping div ?

Comment: @Orbling somehow .position() behaves like .offset() (actually that's what makes me ask this question)

Comment: You can try adding `position: relative` to wrapping div and use `.position()` on span. If that doesn't help just get span's offset and subtract div's offset from it.

Comment: @Ozgur .position() gives the offset relative to whatever parent element the element in question is currently relative to.  Whilst .offset() always gives the position relative to the document.  If the element in question is positioned relative to the document already, then offset() and position() will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should wrap all you span inside an intermediate container (without specifing an height), then calculate the difference between $('#intermediatecontainer').height() and $('#intermediatecontainer').parent().height()

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/DE52m/